# How to change datetime in Vue?

Tags: laravel, datetime, vue.js

Trying to use Vue for the first time.

I dont know how to change the datetime in Vue.

I know it works in laravel, like this:

```
{{  date("d.m.Y", strtotime($file->created_at)) }}
```

How can I change datetime in Vue?

This is what I tried in Vue:

```
<time datetime="1.1.2019">@{{ file.created_at }}</time>
```

and it shows me the exact database entry on the view page:

> 2019-01-25 12:03:40

But I want it to appear like this:

> 25.02.2019 12:03. 40

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Vue method -

```
formattedDate:function(d){
    let arr = d.split(/[- :]/);
    let date = new Date(Date.UTC(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]));
    return date.getDate() + "." + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "." + date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
}
```

And then Call that method within double curly brackets

```
<time datetime="1.1.2019">@{{ formattedDate(file.created_at) }}</time>
```